# Configuration or command to for case insensitive bash history search

Tags: bash, command-history, case-sensitivity

Bash provides the interactive commands `forward-search-history` and `reverse-search-history` typically bound to the keys `CTRL-s` and `CTRL-r` respectively.

Are there case-insentive equivalents or is there a configuration to have these commands case-insensitive?

`bind -P | grep -iE 'search|case'` did not turn out anything relevant.

Comment: I use [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) as replacement for ctrl+r history search and can recommend.

Comment: None, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523393/in-bash-readline-how-do-i-make-the-incremental-search-case-insensitive